# Sum sale amount from one table and update the total to another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, sql-server-ce

Using SQL Server Compact Edition (2008 R2)

1. Tables (`Customer` and `Orders`)
2. PK (Customer : `SID`, Orders : `Customer_SID`)

I want to sum the `Orders.Sales_Amount` and write the totals to `Customer.Sales_Total` based on the `SID`s.

I must be using the `inner join` statement incorrectly as I get an error in the `FROM` statement.

```
UPDATE customer
SET sales_total = aggr.sales_total
FROM customer
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sid
        ,sum(sales_amount) sales_total
    FROM customer
    INNER JOIN orders
        ON (customer.sid = orders.customer_Sid)
    GROUP BY customer.sid
    ) aggr
    ON customer.sid = aggr.sid;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way of accomplishing the update you are after:

```
UPDATE customer
SET sales_total = (SELECT SUM(sales_amount)
                   FROM orders
                   WHERE orders.customer_Sid = customer.sid)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a9db/2)